# Git submodule and git clone create names in lowercase

Tags: git

Why git submodule and clone create directory names in lowercase? How can I get original names, such is if repo name is `RepoName` I would like to add submodule not `reponame` but `RepoName` and the same for cloning.

Comment: What operating system (or more specifically, what file system) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git submodule add` allows to specify the folder you want to use as a placeholder for the submodule to be initialized and updated.

```
git submodule add /url/of/repo myfolder # no trailing /
```

That should be case sensitive, which means you can specify manually the right name with the right case.

Comment: I get `myfolder already exists and is not a valid git repo` error.

Comment: My fault, I was creating `myfolder` and only then executing the command.